# Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient security token expires every 5 hrs, The user authentication failed error occurs

Tags: wcf, dynamics-crm-online

I am new to WCF, I have created the WCF service which connects and pulls the data from dynamic CRM. Everything works fine but after 5 hrs I am getting the below error, because of this error I see the exception `The user authentication failed!`. I understand security token gets expired and because of that I get the authentication error, after restarting the application pool everything seems to be good.

What would cause the security token expire? or how to reissue the token?

`Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Warning: 4 : Claims Connection reset tripped SecurityToken is Not Null Start From is Valid True End At is Valid False Microsoft.Xrm.Tooling.Connector.CrmServiceClient Warning: 4 : Re-Authenticating due to expired token @ 05/20/2021 04:12:23`

I am using `AuthType=IFD` in the connection string and below is my coding, I am passing the connection string from the web.config file. I am using `RequireNewInstance=True;` in the config file as I have a two crm servers to connect.

```
      <add name="crmconnectionstring" connectionString="Url=https://urlhere; AuthType=IFD; RequireNewInstance=True;Domain=testdomain;    Username=testusername; Password=;  " />

public OrganizationServiceProxy service_;
        CrmServiceClient CrmServiceClient_= new 
   CrmServiceClient(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["crmconnectionstring"].ConnectionString);
    if (!CrmServiceClient_.IsReady)
    {
        if (CrmServiceClient_.LastCrmException != null)
           throw CrmServiceClient_.LastCrmException;
       throw new InvalidOperationException(CrmServiceClient_.LastCrmError);
    }
        service_ = CrmServiceClient_.OrganizationServiceProxy;
```

Update 1:

I have tried to renew the token but still it does not work. I am desperately looking for the support.

```
public OrganizationServiceProxy service;
```

service = CrmServiceClient_.OrganizationServiceProxy;
if (null != this.service.SecurityTokenResponse &&
DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(15) >= this.service.SecurityTokenResponse.Response.Lifetime.Expires)
{
try
{
this.service.Authenticate();
}
catch (CommunicationException)
{
if (null == this.service.SecurityTokenResponse ||
DateTime.UtcNow >= this.service.SecurityTokenResponse.Response.Lifetime.Expires)
{
throw;
}
}
}

Comment: About refresh token:https://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/

Comment: Thanks Theoblad but I feel the article is not relevant to me or I do not know how to handle with CRMserviceclient.